# Why would a crimp fly from a terminal?

Tags: crimp

[vacuum cleaner circuit diagram, missing live switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VRhR.jpg)

Attached is a circuit for a vacuum cleaner. Pretty basic, mains, snubber, universal motor. I forgot to draw the switch (spst) on the live wire, before the capacitor junction.

Motor 800W 240V universal

The crimp that connects the wire to the motor (shown with arrow) is dodgy and so is wobbly/not a secure connection. When the vacuum cleaner is turned on, ie switch is closed, immediately with a pop and a flash, the crimp is thrown from the terminal of the motor.

My question is, why would this happen? I am thinking that the spark is ionising the air, and the pop is forcing the crimp off. I also considered that the higher resistance in the bad connection is creating somesort of magnetic flux, perhaps repelling both crimp and terminal from each other, because it uses AC. My last and final idea was the inertia of the spooling motor caused the crimp to flick off.

Maybe it is all three?[image]

Comment: The force on a current carrying wire is radial to the wire direction, but the reason for a wobbly connection is one of defective; design, or process control or excessive environmental stress in strain relief for securing the connection.

Comment: You have it right.  Bad crimp.

Comment: If the crimp is loose then it would arc if it fell off

Comment: then the next  question is why should the crimp  be loose?

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the next question. When I attach the crimp, it's definitely connected. Its wobbly, but still takes half an effort to pull off. Now as soon as I switch the power on, crimp flies off.